# select query with array

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have a table dbo.comp has id and name as columns.

dbo.comp

```
 Name       id
 A           1
 B           2
 C           3
 D           4
 E           5
```

Where B &D is parent name inserted from excel sheet .

excelsheet

```
 parent
   B
   D
```

I need to find out what are the Id’s for the parent names in dbo.comp. For that I stored parent which is present in the excel sheet into a array called parent[j]. And trying to compare with the id presents in the dbo.comp like this. But its not working

```
String Querystring7="SELECT Id from dbo.Comp where Id="+Parent [j]+" ";
```

am writing in java program I stuck writing query for this. How can I get parent name id from dbo.comp by comparing the parent[j] array? Please help me to write a query

Comment: Try to check Parent [j] value is getting or not? For name use single quotes.

Comment: yes Parent[j] has values

Comment: Do you want to check name or id from excelsheet?

Comment: i want id for the parent names. so am comparing the parent[j] of excel sheet with 'Name' in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are storing the `NAME` in the Excel spreadsheet, you should be using the `name` to query your table, not the `ID`, as you are doing.

Example:

```
String Querystring7="SELECT Id from dbo.Comp where Name='"+Parent [j]+"' ";
```

Comment: U've missed the single quotation for string!

Comment: @Traxdata Thanks, corrected! I copied from OPs original query :P

Comment: @user1063145 I corrected the answer. I had forgotten (and you, because I copied your original query), to use the single quote after `Name=...`

Comment: @user1063145 Can you provide the line of code you wrote down?

Answer (score 0):

Parten [J] returns the letter B or D doesn't it?
If so - the query should be something like this...

"SELECT id FROM dbo.comp WHERE NAME = '" + Parent[j] + "'"

Comment: + operator after PARTENT [J] is remaining.